# ant concat, echo Not able to print after variable substitition

Tags: ant, build, ant-contrib

```
<target name="init">
    <loadfile property="Files" srcFile="C:/tabnames.txt">
    </loadfile>
    <foreach list="${Files}"
        target="dbload"
        param="var"
        delimiter="${line.separator}" />
</target>  

<target name="load">
    <echo file="D:/README" append="true">selct * from "${var}" where ******; :${line.separator}</echo>    
    <!--   <concat file="D:/README" append="true">selct * from "${var}" where ******; :${line.separator}</concat> -->
</target>
```

and the output:

```
select * from "a  
select * from "b
```

problem is after variable substitution i am not able to concat ...

i need like

```
select * from "a"  where *******
select * from "b" where ********`
```

EDIT:-

i already have afile...want to add new line as first lne,but its adding as lastline...

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

- You should use [for](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) instead of `<foreach>`. `<for>` doesn't require you to use a separate target in order to work. Remember to use `net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml` when you define the resource and not `net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties`.
- Once a property (Ant doesn't use *variables*), it cannot be changed. What you're passing are *parameters* which you use the `@{var}` syntax for rather than the `${var}` syntax for properties. Parameters are passed with each invocation and can change.

Here's how your routine would look with `<for>`:

```
<for list="${Files}"
    param="var">
    <sequential>
        <echo file="D:/README" 
            append="true"
            message="select * from &quot;@{var}&quot; where ******"/>
   </sequential>
</for>
```

Note the `@{var}` rather than `${var}`.